# Closing Angular Material Dialog returns false but is evaluated as true?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-dialog

I close a MatDialog with `true` and `false`, but somehow I cannot retrieve these boolean values in the correct way. See my code below. The `shouldRefresh` method should not be called, and yet it is.

```
dialogRef.afterClosed()
            .subscribe((result: any): void => {
                console.log('RESULT', result); // Returns false
                if ((result as boolean)) {
                    console.log('Its FALSE ?!?', result); // Fires 
                    this.shouldRefresh.next(true);
                }
            });
```

I cannot figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: What do you expect `result as boolean` does?

Comment: Casting to boolean? It evaluates as false.

Comment: what's the type of result ? `string` ? `boolean` ??

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had:

```
<button mat-dialog-close="false">Cancel</button>
```

But instead I should have added brackets like so:

```
<button [mat-dialog-close]="false">Cancel</button>
```

This passes the result as a `boolean` and not as a `string`.

The joys of programming.